# Difference between engine rev up and run-up

Tags: jet-engine

Explain please the difference between these jet engine terms:

- **rev up**
- **run up**

Obviously they are completely different procedures. The reason I ask this question is because I'm not a native speaker and have some problems differentiating these 2 things. 
You don't necessarily have to go deeply into technical details about these two procedures, however **it would be welcomed** ;)

Comment: I've never heard of engine rev up.

Comment: [In english revving an engine is another way of saying "hit the throttle"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revving) while a [run up is a pre-takeoff procedure](https://www.askacfi.com/118/is-a-engine-run-up-really-necessary.htm) the majority of uses for these terms is with piston engines. Can you supply some more context to your question?

Comment: As a non-native speaker, this would have probably been a better fit at [ELL.se], even though you got a fine answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general English usage, including in aviation, "rev up" is a verb form describing the act of increasing the speed of something.  "Rev up the engine" just means give it a shot of power to make it go faster.

"Run up", as used in this case, is actually a noun, describing a procedure to test an engine against go-no-go criteria.  "Do an engine run-up" means perform the run-up procedure, which may include accelerating the engine to a specific speed to put things under a bit of stress, and testing various systems while at speed to detect degraded or failed components or subsystems that are revealed only when under stress.